# How to use powerMockito + testng to test

Tags: java, mockito, testng, powermockito

I want to use powerMockito + testng to test，the test code is ：
and my powerMockito version is 1.6.3，testng version is 6.8.7

```
@PrepareForTest(ClassWithStatics.class)
```

public class mockTest  {

```
@ObjectFactory
public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
    return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
}

public static String getString() {
    return "111";
}

public static int getInt() {
    return 1;
}


@Test
public void test() throws Exception   {

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassWithStatics.class);
    PowerMockito.when(ClassWithStatics.getString()).thenReturn("999");
    System.out.println("String: " + ClassWithStatics.getString());
}
```

}

but the error code is:

> FAILED: test java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError    at
>   org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
>     at
>   org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:41)
>     at
>   org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.(MockitoException.java:30)
>     at
>   org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MockitoConfigurationException.(MockitoConfigurationException.java:18)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:66)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:24)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.(PluginRegistry.java:12)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.(Plugins.java:11)
>     at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.(MockUtil.java:24)

Comment: What version of Mockito do you use?

Comment: Please post the full source of both classes - `mockTest` and `ClassWithStatics` - I think it's possible you have mixed them in your question. Also double-check your jar dependencies - if you are using maven then these are defined [here](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/Mockito_testng_maven) in the PowerMock docs.